# how to create a pie chart from csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pie-chart

I have [this CSV data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17gJUiO3e26jXbcE76S81A6o_XA2x_coM), I'm trying to make a pie chart using this data

I'm a beginner in python and don't understand how to create a pie chart using the three columns, please help!

working solution code would be more helpful!

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_csv ('chart_work.csv')

product_data = df["Product Name;"]   
bug_data = df["Number Of Bugs"]                      
colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728", "#8c564b"]    

plt.pie(bug_data , labels=product_data , colors=colors,
autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)

plt.show()
```

the pie chart which is outputed by this code is distorted, any help?

**Chart I'm getting:**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very simple.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import pie, axis, show
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv ('chart_work.csv')

sums = df.groupby(df["Product Name;"])["Number Of Bugs"].sum()
axis('equal');
pie(sums, labels=sums.index);
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The pie chart does not 'know' that you want all items with same product name grouped and summed over in your chart. so you have to do that first:

```
df = df.groupby(["Product Name;"]).sum()
```

This sets the product name column as index of the df so change your product_data column selection to this:

```
product_data = df.index
```

Comment: where to include this piece of code ? please help me with detailed explanation or working code.

Comment: it seems to me that you still don't really understand 1) what your code does 2) why it does not give the desired result and 3) what my solution does to change the result. If you have questions regarding your understanding of a) - c) I'm happy to answer them. But I will not just post the working solution that you can copy and paste without understanding.

Comment: yeah i am learning python now but i have this task of finishing this up by tomorrow so googled and was able to generate a pie chart which was that result, i am happy to learn but i have no idea where this piece of code goes, should i get into this task after learning python basics? give me advice i need it, totally confused what to do!

Comment: the first line of the answer goes right after the loading of the csv file (4th line). the second one replaces ´product_data = df["Product Name;"]´.  
  the answer from ashok does basically the same thing. just look at the similar ´groupby´ statements. if you are using a jupyter notebook (or any other environment) I would enter each line one by one and look at the resulting dataframe how it changes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sizes=[89,80,90,100,75]
lables=["swetha","yokesh","iswarya","ranjeeth","deepika"]
plt.pie(sizes,lables=lables,autopct="%.2f")
plt.axes().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```